# MYSQL NOT IN with multiple column names

Tags: mysql

i have 2 mysql queries,
1 is to select the all branch stocks and other is to select stock count lists.
i need to select all the branch stocks which is not included in stock count lists( by considering stock barcode and stock batch)

my first query to select all branch stock is

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  stock_id  ,product_name , stock_batch,stock_barcode 
   FROM stock INNER JOIN product ON product_id = stock_product 
   LEFT JOIN packing ON product_package=packing_id    
   WHERE  stock_branch  = 2 AND stock_available_flg = 1   
   group by stock_id
```

and second query to select counted stock lists is

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS stock_id,stock_barcode, product_name,stock_batch  FROM stock_count_item 
INNER JOIN stock ON stock_id = stock_count_item_stock 
INNER JOIN product ON stock_product = product_id 
INNER JOIN category ON category_id = product_category 
WHERE stock_count_item_stock_count = 42 GROUP BY stock_barcode
```

what i need is to select all branch stock which is not included in stock count lsts with same barcode and batch

my query is

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  stock_id  ,product_name ,           stock_batch,stock_barcode 
FROM stock 
INNER JOIN product ON product_id = stock_product 
LEFT JOIN packing ON product_package=packing_id    
WHERE  stock_branch = 2 AND stock_available_flg = 1  AND ( stock_batch,stock_barcode)  
not in 
(SELECT  stock_batch ,stock_barcode FROM stock_count_item 
INNER JOIN stock ON stock_id = stock_count_item_stock 
INNER JOIN product ON stock_product = product_id 
INNER JOIN category ON category_id = product_category WHERE stock_count_item_stock_count = 42)
```

but this not gives the correct result .How am consider  stock_batch,stock_barcode together  to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN

**BUT** because you have not identified which tables each column comes from so I (or anyone maintaining your code) cannot learn a column's source from reading the query. *ALWAYS prefix the column by the table (or table's alias).*

```
SELECT
      SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS stock_id
    , product_name
    , stock_batch
    , stock_barcode
FROM stock
      INNER JOIN product ON product_id = stock_product
      LEFT JOIN packing ON product_package = packing_id
WHERE stock_branch = 2
      AND stock_available_flg = 1
      NOT NOT EXSTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM stock_count_item
                  INNER JOIN stock ON stock_id = stock_count_item_stock
                  INNER JOIN product ON stock_product = product_id
                  INNER JOIN category ON category_id = product_category
            WHERE stock_count_item_stock_count = 42
             and outer_alias.stock_batch = inner_alias.stock_batch
             and outer_alias.stock_barcode = inner_alias.stock_barcode
      )
;
```

I have tried to indicate what is required by using

and **outer_alias**.stock_batch = **inner_alias**.stock_batch

the "outer_alias" is an alias (or tablename) from **before** the NOT EXISTS subquery, and the inner_alias is the reverse. At least one of these has to be an alias if you choose to use a tablename for one of hem.

**e.g.**

select ... from **stock** where not exists (... from stock **s** and **stock**.id = **s**.id)

- "stock" is the "outer_alias" of stock.id
- "s" is the "inner_alias" of s.id

---

the final query with aliases (via comment below)

```
SELECT
      SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS stock_id
    , product_name
    , s.stock_batch --<< please please please use aliases everywhere
    , s.stock_barcode
FROM stock s
      INNER JOIN product ON product_id = stock_product
      LEFT JOIN packing ON product_package = packing_id
WHERE stock_branch = 2
      AND stock_available_flg = 1
      AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT
                  1
            FROM stock_count_item
                  INNER JOIN stock st ON stock_id = stock_count_item_stock
                  INNER JOIN product ON stock_product = product_id
                  INNER JOIN category ON category_id = product_category
            WHERE stock_count_item_stock_count = 42
                  AND s.stock_batch = st.stock_batch
                  AND s.stock_barcode = st.stock_barcode
      )
```

Comment: SELECT  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS stock_id  , product_name , stock_batch, stock_barcode FROM stock s INNER JOIN product ON product_id = stock_product LEFT JOIN packing ON product_package = packing_id WHERE stock_branch = 2 AND stock_available_flg = 1 and NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1   FROM stock_count_item INNER JOIN stock st ON stock_id = stock_count_item_stock INNER JOIN product ON stock_product = product_id  INNER JOIN category ON category_id = product_category    WHERE stock_count_item_stock_count = 42
             and s.stock_batch = st.stock_batch
             and s.stock_barcode = st.stock_barcode)

Comment: excellent. thanks for the follow-up. I do very sincerely advise you to include tabe or alias prefixes to **all** column references. Yes it's more tedious to write, but boy does it make a vast difference when you maintain the code!!!